# Jquery bind several functions to one element

Tags: bind, jquery, jquery-1.3.2

Strange, is there no possibility to put several binds in jquery, on one element?

```
$('input').click(clickfn).click(clickfn)
```

I am using 1.3.2

```
function clickme() { alert('click me') }

$('.click', mod).bind("brrr", clickme).bind("brrr", clickme)
                .click(function() { $('.click', mod).trigger("brrr"); });
```

This is not working also. Executes one time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have there should work just fine… it does for me (also with jQuery 1.3.2). Try this:

```
$('input').click(function(ev){ alert('func 1'); }).click(function(ev){ alert('func 2'); });
```

When you click the `input` elements, you should see consecutive alerts appear. Perhaps you are returning `false` in the first function? This would stop event propagation, so the second handler wouldn't be fired.

As an aside, I see you're doing this to `input` elements, so you probably want to use the [`focus`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/focus#fn) event instead of `click`.

Comment: I found what happened, it was deleting this element in first action.